# How does this pattern work?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I was reading a blog post on the [Anthony Williams website](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/blog/) when I somehow wandered onto an example of his just::thread library, his [barber shop example](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/all-the-worlds-a-stage.html).

In it he has a series of a structures that doesn't inherit from anything:

```
struct start_haircut {};
struct no_room {};
struct shop_closed {};
```

He then has a [`receive`](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/actor/actor/receive.html) function that he chains the `.match()` template to:

```
jss::actor::receive()
    .match<start_haircut>(
        [&](start_haircut){
            //...
        })
    .match<no_room>(
        [&](no_room){
            //...
        })
    .match<shop_closed>(
        [&](shop_closed)
        {
            //...
        });
```

The receive function returns an `unspecified_message_receiver` object that specifies the type (`shop_closed`, etc.) and the lambda handler.

What goes inside the `receive` and `match` functions? How does the `receive` and `match` functions interact?

This is an interesting pattern that can have applications outside the threading model it is used on. I am interested in it for communications over tcp between sensors where small message packets and small amounts of data are being transferred continuously.

Comment: Looks like some form of tag dispatch. Also, this is more of an "implementation pattern" than a "design pattern", I'd say.

Comment: If there is a better tag then feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks (unsurprisingly) like Erlang.

This is pretty clearly described in the documentation you linked to, and quoted.

> The receive function returns an `unspecified_message_receiver` object

so `jss::actor::receive()` is an `unspecified_message_receiver`,

> Calling `match()` on a receiver adds the specified `MsgType` to the list of handled messages, and registers the specified handler to be called when a message of that type is received.

so

```
.match<start_haircut>(
    [&](start_haircut){
        //...
    })
```

registers the lambda to handle messages of type `start_haircut`, in the receiver returned previously.
Since each `match` returns a message receiver, you can chain them to register more handlers.

I'm not sure what else can be said to clarify, but a more realistic use might employ some types that carry some kind of payload, such as

```
struct start_haircut { enum { Long, Short, Shaved } style; };

jss::actor::receive()
    .match<start_haircut>(
        [&](start_haircut cut){
            switch (cut.style)
            {
                case start_haircut::Long:
                // ...
            }
        })
    .match<no_room>(
        [&](no_room){
            //...
        })
    .match<shop_closed>(
        [&](shop_closed)
        {
            //...
        });
```

(This kind of interface probably makes more sense if you take a peek at an Erlang tutorial, like ["Learn you some Erlang for great good!"](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content)).

Comment: I can see that you can chain more types and I was thinking about payloads for the comms.  My main focus is the return of `unspecified_message_receiver` since no object derives of that and doesn't seem to get passed how does it return.  What does the internals of match look like?  I've been reading up on tag_dispatch like @kerrek_sb suggested.

Comment: @graham.reeds The internals of the library costs a minimum of GBP 150 to look at and you won't find anyone posting them here. There are also other actor implementations in C++, so you might want to look around.

Comment: I don't want anyone to post the internals, but there must be a generic pattern underpinning it and that is what I am trying to grok.

Answer (score 0):

Here  is one way to achieve it, be wary though as it uses runtime info instead of compile time information to achieve this, which may not be the way that the C++ template magician would achieve the solution :)!
godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/yZC8sM
You can try this online using ideone.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Erased {
    virtual ~Erased(){};
};

template <typename T>
struct Handler : public Erased {
    std::function<void(T)> handl;
};

struct cont {

  template<typename T>
  void handle(T msg) {
    const std::type_info *t = &typeid(T);
    auto iter = handlers.find(t);
    if(iter != handlers.end()) {

      dynamic_cast<Handler<T>*>(iter->second.get())->handl(msg);
    }
  }

  template <typename T>
  void match(std::function<void (T)> handler) {
    auto realHandler = std::make_shared<Handler<T>>();
    realHandler->handl = handler;
    const std::type_info* t = &typeid(T);
    handlers.insert(std::make_pair(t, realHandler));
  }

  std::map<const std::type_info*, std::shared_ptr<Erased>> handlers;


};

int main() {
  cont container;
  container.match<int>([](int x) { std::cout << " got  avalue of ... " << x; });
  container.handle(5);         
}
```

Just wanted to fill in on my answer here:
What i've written above is a solution using the runtime data to do this dispatch ( much simpler to understand), however you can create such dispatch using compile time dispatchers without std::map at all. small notes how -

You need to create a special type for each chain that is:
`.match([](int&) { ...}).match([](double&) {. ..  });` where each match would create a complete new type with multiple methods, then using the type erasure you will get a generic type on which you can do a virtual dispatch to that erased type - and then using template generated code invoke your desired handler.